# Save files and uploading in the same time

Tags: c#

I am writing an application which create files based on timestamp each 1 second, then move them to another folder, then send them as post to a webservice which save them on the folder.
When running the generating function it generates successfully.
When runnng the upload function it upload them successfully.
But when running both of them and a backgroundworker components, the first works perfectly, but the upload mechanism tell em that the file is opened by another proccess.
How can I solve that?
Thx

Comment: Are you closing the created file after writing it to the disk?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice when dealing with classes that implement the IDisposable interface, such as the file stream class, is to wrap these classes usage in a unsing statement. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream.aspx):

```
    //Create the file.
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
    {
        AddText(fs, "This is some text");
        AddText(fs, "This is some more text,");
        AddText(fs, "\r\nand this is on a new line");
        AddText(fs, "\r\n\r\nThe following is a subset of characters:\r\n");

        for (int i=1;i < 120;i++)
        {
            AddText(fs, Convert.ToChar(i).ToString());

        }
    }
```

Another thing that you should be aware of is multi-threading synchronization. Maybe your "upload" background worker is trying to access the file before your "generate file" background worker had time to finish creating it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ks4uu6csdk3691g/3%20functions%20in%20the%20same%20time%20-%20localhost.zip